# accessing pci configuration space in real mode

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, pci

I'm trying to write assembly to access pci configuration space.

what I'm trying to do is basically what this article does.

https://sites.google.com/site/pinczakko/pinczakko-s-guide-to-award-bios-reverse-engineering

[image]

my question is, because I'm trying to do this in real mode, and pci configuration has to be accessed by 32 bits data... can I do this in real mode? the register like eax is accessible in real mode? or do I need to move to protected mode to do this?

Comment: Yes, 32-bit operations work fine in real mode.  They're encoded with an operand size override prefix.  Just make sure your assembler is set to 16-bit mode and write `out dx, eax` and your assembler will emit it with the prefix.

Comment: The code is using `pushad`/`popad` specifically so it can assemble for 16-bit mode and still save the full register, not `pusha`/`popa` which might assemble as `pushaw` in  `bits 16` mode in some assemblers.  You could just try it to see how `mov eax, 123456` assembles in 16-bit code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> pci configuration has to be accessed by 32 bits data... can I do this in real mode?

Yes; "real mode" just means the default operand size is 16-bit, but you (the assembler) can change the default using a size override prefix.

Of course this only works on 32-bit CPUs (80386 or later), but I doubt you'll care because computers that old won't support PCI anyway (but it's good practice to have an "does the CPU support 32 bit?" check to avoid crashing with no explanation on very old computers).

For newer computers (with PCI express) "PCI config space" was increased to 4 KiB per function (from the original 256 bytes of PCI config space per function) and a new memory mapped PCI configuration space mechanism was added to make it much faster (without slow IO ports). You won't be able to use memory mapped PCI configuration space mechanism in real mode. Fortunately (for backward compatibility reasons); the old "IO ports" access mechanism is still supported (but only lets you access the first 256 bytes of each function's 4096 bytes) and the extra PCI configuration space for each function is mostly used by things that you won't be able to use anyway (e.g. message signaled interrupts, power management, ...).

Comment: thanks for the answer! the register I'm trying to access is chipset configuration register and it has 16bits offset value... 0400h-0403h... but pci configuration mechanism 1 only has bit 2-7, which is 6bit available for offset value... and chipset datasheet says pci configuration space is accessed by configuration mechanism 1... do you know why???? and how to access it?

Comment: sorry I think you probably answered it... it's by memory mapped method... I'll look into it. thank you

Comment: datasheet says it! " this block is mapped into memory space using root complex base address... "

Comment: @MK: Normally (for the IO port access mechanism) you access whole 32-bit values; and then use masking/shifting to select smaller fields inside that larger 32-bit piece (like `uint16_t foo = PCI_readDword(offset & 0xFC) >> 16;` maybe).